# How to make "condition for component" in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, conditional-statements

I want to make condition if this.props === "0", the component will show on screen and when else, the component will hide. How to make it?

I tried use react-native condition and doesn't work

this for my code:

```
{data.is_approved === '0' ? (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress = {() => this.deleteTrancation(data.id, data.sales_id)}
    style={[styles.icons, common.backgroundWarn]}
  >
    <Icon name="clear" size={18} color={color.colorOff} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
) : (
  <Text style={[common.textValid]}></Text>
)}
```

my complete code: https://pastebin.com/U9p5akdi

I expect when string "0", the component will show and else, the component will hide

Comment: What is `this.props.data`? An object?

Comment: yes sir, this.props.data is object

Comment: Then your condition is correct. What is the issue here?

Comment: when data.is_approved is string "0", touchableOpacity will show. When data.is_approved is string "1", TouchableOpacity will hide from screen

Comment: And what about `<Text style={[common.textValid]}></Text>`? when you want this to be visible?

Comment: Your current condition is doing the same, isn't it? What is the problem with this condition.

Comment: when I run this condition, this condition always return in false condition
and when I typeof(data.is_approved), data.is_approved return undefined datatype

Comment: This means your data is not passed properly.

Comment: what is missing from my code?
and where do I need to add it?

Comment: Nothing wrong in this code, probably your props are wrong.

Comment: where I can fix that?

Comment: Can you post parent component where you are passing props?

Comment: that's parent component

Comment: Then from where you are receiving props?

Comment: I think from this : <https://pastebin.com/NUdkcpek>

I dont know because I new contributor for this project

Answer (score 0):

See whether if it works. May be you missed integer type as 
string type

```
{data.is_approved === 0 ? (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress = {() => this.deleteTrancation(data.id, data.sales_id)}
                      style={[styles.icons, common.backgroundWarn]}>
                    <Icon name="clear" size={18} color={color.colorOff} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  ) : (
                    <Text style={[common.textValid]}></Text>
                  )}
```

Comment: for the condition, that's used string type from the API

Comment: Use type casting conversion. Integer.parseInt(string)

Answer (score 0):

**its working for any condition 0 is string OR Number**

```js
{ 
data.is_approved == '0' 
?
<TouchableOpacity/>
:
<Text style={[common.textValid]}></Text>
}
```

Comment: but for now, data.is_approved have undefined datatype

is my code wrong?

Comment: first you have console.log(data.is_approved)

Comment: that's return undefined

Comment: when you receive data from prop it not receive pls check in props data received or not

Comment: sorry, where I can check that props data?

Comment: in componentwillmount you have to check your props data

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample on codesandbox of working sample for you.

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-04dfj
>
> FirstComponent

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import SecondComp from "./SecondComp";

class FirstComp extends Component {
  state = {
    renderSecond: true
  };

  render() {
    const { renderSecond } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        Change renderSecond state of FirstComp {renderSecond && <SecondComp />}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default FirstComp;
```

> Second Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SecondComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Rendering Second Component</div>;
  }
}

export default SecondComp;
```

In the first component there is a state

```
 state = {
        renderSecond: true
      };
You can change the renderSecond value to false and second component will not render.
Please check the link for working sample and you can even pass this value as prop from the parent component
```

Answer (score 0):

you shold pass some flag like ShowSecondComponent" to the second component from 1st component.

In your 1st component code

```js
<Fragment>
        Change renderSecond state of FirstComp {renderSecond && <SecondComp ShowSecondComponent ={this.state.renderSecond} />}
 </Fragment
```

Receive the prop in second component and use it inside render method of second component with if.

```js
class SecondComp extends Component {
  render() {
    if(!this.props.ShowSecondComponent) return null;
     
    return <div>Rendering Second Component</div>;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps